# How do I edit a laptop screen with the same resolution as a desktop monitor with CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I have this problem where I have a laptop with 1920x1080 and my monitor 1920x1080. Both will respond to the CSS, but they won't be the same.
The nav bar for example will be wider on one screen while it'll be what I want it on the other? 
Anyone know how to get around this problem, I tried using `@media (max-resolution:140dpi)` but it doesn't seem to work or I'm using it wrong.

Comment: Does actual size of monitors is same? Screen pixel is not same as CSS pixel, so Retina and LCD screens will have same size pixel, no matter of actual pixels

Comment: No, the laptop is 15.6inchs and the monitor 27inchs.

Comment: So that's why you have different views

Comment: Are you asking how to ensure that something is the same number of centimeters wide on different displays? (That's almost always a terrible design goal)

Comment: I'm just looking, for example the navbar to in line with the body on both displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it, I used `@media screen and (min-resolution: 141dpi)` just for anyone who may have this problem in the future.